# Scraping a lazy loading website using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to build a simple Web Scraping Project on [Goibibo.com](https://www.goibibo.com/) and am trying to work on [this](https://www.goibibo.com/hotels/hotels-in-delhi-ct/) page specifically.

Generally, my approach to scraping any dynamic website is to scroll down until I have enough data to scrape, then load the HTML into BeautifulSoup to scrape.
But in this case, the website uses some kind of lazy loading where it loads only the elements visible to the user are rendered in HTML and the ones the user scroll pasts are removed.
So, if I try to parse the HTML data I find about 6-10 hotels in the soup.

I want to find a way to extract all of the hotels on this page. I initially thought of scrolling to each `div` of each posting but I am not sure how I can achieve that.

Here's what I have done so far

```py
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.binary_location = "chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
link = "https://www.goibibo.com/hotels/hotels-in-delhi-ct/"
driver.get(link)
driver.maximize_window()
sleep(2)

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight*(0.75))") #75% as the footer is tall
sleep(2)

showMore = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='root']/div[2]/div/section[2]/button") #Clicking the show more button
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight*(0.75))")
showMore[0].click()

for _ in range(10):

    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
    sleep(1)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight-2000)") 
    # Hacky way to load more listings as the loading was stuck for some reason until I scrolled again
    sleep(2)

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
```

Comment: An idea would be to target the data you need with your XPATH and build an array. (get text, attribute,  innerHTML... whatever it is you need to store)  If the data does not exist in your array, add it.  Do that before each scroll.

Comment: Would a simple == operator or `in` work in that case to check the previous elements? Since the strings would be very long. I'm not sure...

Comment: I don't know python... in Java you'd use an arraylist I think and check "contains".  Would essentially be the same as equal.  It shouldn't matter how long the strings are... they're either repeats or not.

Comment: Alright, will try this!